# Vertical scrollbar in Div appears with overflow auto and height auto

Tags: html, css

I have a div set with overflow:auto and also height: auto. The div contains text data and a big image.
I have verified using firebug these attributes are being applied fine, but still scrollbar appears vertically. I will like div to expand automatically to required height.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: The div's height is being constrained by something else in your HTML.  Without seeing the HTML and CSS, there is no way we can answer this question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Problem resolved by removing line-height attributes in one of the parent styles.

Comment: set the height to 100% if you want it to expand automatically, overflow: auto will set a scollbar where necessary, whether horizontally or vertically http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp see here for more if you want a single direction for scroll use overflow-x or overflow-y for the respective axis

Comment: @TheLegend No, the height should be its default of `auto` if you want it to expand automatically. `100%` restricts it to the height of its parent.